# Understanding the purpose of REFT and REFB on a differential ADC

Tags: adc, differential, voltage-reference

I am using the Analog Devices AD9238 ADC for a project and I am confused about the purpose of the differential voltage references (REFT and REFB).

I am powering the AD9238 from a +3.0V supply and I set the VREF of the ADC to +1.0V by pulling the SENSE pin to ground as specified in the data sheet. According to page 16 of the data sheet the values of REFT, REFB and the Span can be calculated as follows:

$$ REFT = 0.5 \cdot (AVDD + VREF) $$
$$ REFB = 0.5 \cdot (AVDD - VREF) $$
$$ Span = 2 \cdot (REFT - REFB) = 2 \cdot VREF $$

If I use the above equations I get the following values: REFT = 2V, REFB = 1V and Span = 2V. According to page 16 of the data sheet the values of REFT and REFB create internal positive and negative reference voltages, respectively, that define the span of the ADC core.

Here is how I interpret the meaning of REFT and REFB. The image below illustrates what I understand. The green and purple traces are the single-ended signals which are fed into the ADC, these signals swing between 2V (REFT) and 1V (REFB) around a common mode voltage of 1.5V (mid supply voltage). The input signals form a 2V peak to peak differential signal shown as the black trace. Based on the ADC configuration (VREF = 1V) this is the maximum input signal the ADC can sample. All this makes sense to me.

[image: Common Mode Input Voltage 1.5V]

However, the ADC data sheet goes on to state that the minimum and maximum common-mode input levels are defined as:

$$ VCM_{min} = 0.5 \cdot VREF $$
$$ VCM_{max} = 0.5 \cdot (AVDD + VREF) $$

If I use these equations to calculate the minimum and maximum VCM values I get, 0.5V and 2V, respectively. If I provide a signal to the ADC which has a common mode voltage of 0.5V (first image below) or 2V (second image below) then both these signals do not swing between REFT and REFB. So if the ADC can sample signals outside REFT and REFB then what is the purpose of REFT and REFB. In my understanding REFT and REFB provide the minimum and maximum reference values for the ADC so that the ADC can compare the input signal to these values and encode the sampled signal accordingly but I clearly have a miss understanding of the purpose of REFT and REFB. Can someone please inform me where I am going wrong.

Thank you!

[image: Common Mode Input Voltage 0.5V]

[image: Common Mode Input Voltage 2V]